# take times from specific column in a string format and turn into datetime objects python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to take a specific value from a dataframe and transform it into a datetime object to be used to analyze other information.

The dataframe looks like this below.

```
<bound method NDFrame.to_clipboard of   medication dosage_times            medication_activity_time gender age
0    Caffeine            3  ["09:00 AM","12:00 PM","03:00 PM"]   Male  30>
```

Then using this command,

```
Settings.medication_activity_time[0]
```

I get this output which is a string

```
'["09:00 AM","12:00 PM","03:00 PM"]'
```

Using python is there a way to properly take these specific values and make them usable in another dataframe?

Thanks

Comment: Try `json.loads(Settings.medication_activity_time[0])`

Comment: We have methods in pandas to do that...but  just curious... you have only timestamp in  your string , but does not have any date

Comment: Oh yes you're right. It is just a timestamp - So I suppose I just want the timestamp to be put into a new specific column!